# Adjusting size of barcode image output

Tags: python, image, barcode

I am trying to adjust the size of a barcode output

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

bar_class = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
barcode = '1234567890'
writer=ImageWriter()
writer.set_options({module_width:2, module_height:2})
code128 = bar_class(barcode, writer)
code128.save('filename')
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'module_width' is not defined
```

I dont really understand how to use the documentation found here: https://pythonhosted.org/pyBarcode/writers/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you generated an image of any size you can resize it using `PIL`

```py
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import PIL
from PIL import Image

bar_class = barcode.get_barcode_class('code128')
barcode = '1234567890'

writer=ImageWriter()
code128 = bar_class(barcode, writer)

code128.save('filename') # save the originally generated image

to_be_resized = Image.open('filename.png') # open in a PIL Image object

newSize = (500, 300) # new size will be 500 by 300 pixels, for example
resized = to_be_resized.resize(newSize, resample=PIL.Image.NEAREST) # you can choose other :resample: values to get different quality/speed results

resized.save('filename_resized.png') # save the resized image
```

more on [PIL.Image.resize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

Comment: This solution works however when I use pyFPDF to add the image to a pdf, the preview of the pdf on the server looks OK however when I download the PDF, for some reason the quality decreases and it cant be read by a barcode reader

Comment: maybe you have some compression happening on the server side, try not using pdf, try to upload just an image the the server and download it from the server, check if quality decreases

Comment: You have to be careful when resizing a barcode.  Using NEAREST as you did can change the relative widths of different bars, possibly to the point of not being readable.  Any other option will introduce some blurriness at the bar edges.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem by changing this line

```
code128.save('filename', {"module_width":0.35, "module_height":10, "font_size": 18, "text_distance": 1, "quiet_zone": 3})
```

without using another liabrary.

Answer (score 3):

See that!
I solved my problem exactly like this, when saving, I did it as follows::

**IMPORTANT: Without another library!**

```
ean = barcode.get('ean13', setbarcodehere, writer=ImageWitoutTextWriter())
filename = ean.save(setfilenamehere, {"module_width":0.35, "module_height":10, "font_size": 18, "text_distance": -3, "quiet_zone": 1})
filename
print('Done! :D, {}'.format(filename))
```

**Example:**

[image: Here U can see the image output.]